How to Enable USB Debugging (Security Settings) on a Poco X3 Pro with a Broken Screen for scrcpy and Backup My Data First?
I have a Poco X3 Pro with a broken screen (the screen doesn’t turn on, it’s just dimly lit in Fastboot and during boot) due to water damage, and I need to control it from my PC using scrcpy. The phone is unrooted, and I can’t access the UI due to the broken display. I can temporarily install TWRP (even though it reverts after reboot).
I want to use scrcpy to control the phone, but to do so, I need to enable USB debugging (Security Settings), which I can’t do without access to the screen
Here’s what I can do:

The phone can enter Fastboot mode, and I can temporarily install TWRP.
USB Debugging is already enabled.
USB Debugging (Security Settings) is disabled. (Xiaomi devices require this toggled on)
to be able to use scrcpy
I have no access to the screen or UI.

Before making any changes, I’d like to back up all my important data (apps, system data, personal files) or do a full-phone backup as a precaution, in case the process is risky or anything goes wrong during the procedure.

I would try first using an USB mouse. Use it directly to control the UI or use it to pair a Bluetooth mouse.

"USB Debugging (Security Settings) is disabled." You can control still the device with UHID: scrcpy -KM.
